# What is the benefit to having a network's HTTP traffic sent out on a different IP than HTTPS?

Tags: networking, iis, web-server, http, https

I've noticed that some traffic coming to my web sites reports a different source IP depending on whether or not the connection is secure.  I have two different hostnames, one of which is HTTP, the other, HTTPS, which point to different IPs on the same server.  I'm seeing this from users coming from specific networks:

```
Requests to http://www.example.com come from 1.1.1.1
Requests to https://secure.example.com come from 1.1.1.2
```

The secure source IP is often just one off from the non-secure source IP, and I'm pretty sure it's the same user making the requests.

What is the benefit of setting up a network like this?  I'm assuming it has something to do with security or analytics, but I can't think of a reason why.

Comment: Do the requests have an X-Forwarded-For header? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: I'm unfortunately unable to see at the moment, since IIS does not log that header automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few possible benefits from setting up a proxy system this way:

- Allows you to classify traffic in your network for QoS/Policing on Layer 3 only devices
- More available ephemeral ports
- Allows you to bypass traffic throughput licensing limitations on an IDS by excluding traffic it may not be able to inspect
- Lets you troll other admins/log watchers who go 'huh' when they see your traffic!

There are also a few downsides:

- Some sites use IP information for visitor tracking and this could break things (this is pretty rare)
- Makes diagnosing problems more difficult as traffic may come from two different places
- Depending on how close the IP addresses are (netblock wise) it could actually take a different route over the internet which could mean confusing performance issues

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be they are using some sort of firewall/proxy that is content scrubbing HTTP requests, but is unable to scrub HTTPS requests, so those go out via another source.  I'd really be surprised if a large percentage of your traffic appears this way.

Comment: It's definitely a minority.  Only a small handful of our users come from a network that does this, though it's enough to cause me grief.

Comment: This is a guess at how they are doing it, the question was what are the possible benefits.

Answer (score 1):

They probably have transparent caching proxy (squid?), which uses one IP and all other direct traffic (including HTTPS) is going to your server directly using another IP.

Comment: This is a guess at how they are doing it, the question was what are the possible benefits.